# ¿Por qué esta función flecha devuelve 1?

Tags: javascript, funciones, function

Tengo este código en JS:

```js
function foo() {
  var f = () => arguments[0]; // Referencia al objeto arguments
  console.log(f(2));
  return f(2);
}

foo(1); // 1
```

Y me devuelve 1, para nada entiendo el por qué de este comportamiento. Debería devolver 2, ya que `arguments` almacena los parametros pasados a la función en su contexto y `arguments[0]`, será siempre 2, debido a `return f(2)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La función devuelve 1 porque `arguments` pertenece a la función foo, es decir, el contexto es el de la función principal.

Las funciones `Flechas` (`Arrow Functions`) carecen de `this`, `arguments`, `super`, o `new.target`. En pocas palabras, este tipo de funciones no tienen contexto, es por esto que se toma la variable arguments de la función foo. [Ver documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions)

He creado una función de ejemplo para que puedas validar la diferencia.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('Argumentos de foo', arguments);
  var f = function() {
    console.log('Argumentos de f', arguments);
    return arguments[0]
  }
  return f(5,6,7);
}

console.log(foo(1));
```

Comment: Ahora lo veo clarísimo, muchas gracias !

Comment: De nada estimado!